Upgrade from 24.04 release-candidate / daily to official release
I installed the "release candidate" a few days before the official release.  How do I upgrade to the official release without having to download the new CD image?
All of the branding, /etc/apt/sources..., and "About" info seem to indicate that I am running 24.04 .... So, I wonder whether the OS automatically becomes the official release as of the date of the official release?

The release candidate images are what are hoped to be released as the final image... Yes if problems are discovered in late testing a new RC image is created (apt full-upgrade is the most you'll need for this, though apt upgrade should get you there too) but the last RC becomes the released ISO  (you didn't specify product, but contrast date of ISO with released image; your image may have been final).  View apt update or /var/log/installer/mediainfo to view your ISO detail.

Prior to initial public release Ubuntu makes available a pre-release of the next upcoming release which once installed and periodically updated simply is that version ... such a machine is that release before and after public release
periodically issue below to stay current with package changes
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade

If you are a software developer below paragraph matters, yet if you simply wish to use Ubuntu to launch a browser to get online ignore following paragraph and just install the latest Ubuntu release.
Every two years on even years (  2020,  2022,  2024 ... ) Ubuntu releases its long term supported version LTS on the 04 month ( April ) of that year ( 2024.04 ) which is what some big 3rd party project packages support ( think docker ) ... every 6 months Ubuntu releases an interim release ( 2022.10,  2023.04,  2023.10 ... ) however these are often not directly supported by large 3rd party packages ( docker, etc ) without a little tinkering to update a given packages entry file found below dir /etc/apt
